# Which replacement Zener Diode should I use?

Tags: power-supply, diodes

I am repairing a television power supply and have found a couple Zener Diodes that are bad. The service manual gives only a part number of VZMTZJ30DT. I have searched online for hours and cannot find any information on this component. Any help would be great.

I am working on a Panasonic power supply ETX2MM-806-AEL, and the component location is ZD501 and ZD503.

Comment: Are you sure VZ is actually part of the part number? Vz often means zener voltage, which I assume will be 30V in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a [MTZJ30](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/395/MTZJ%20Series_B13-523639.pdf) 30V 500mW Zener.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the VZMTZJ30DT is no longer made. But I find it very strange that after hours of online searching, I cannot find  datasheet

Comment: Part number prefixes tend to be manufacturer-dependent, suffixes package dependent.